# Is there a way to use a list of URLs using python using the import requests? r = requests.get('https://{redacted by me}/vessels/amadi_9682552_100037

Tags: python

I would like to use a list of URLs to process their data using python.  I can obtain the information using one URL but I would like to from many.

The following code gets me the data that I need although I am unable to use a list for example where #myString  I am on day few learning python.

```
import requests

#myString = ['https://{redacted by me}/vessels/amadi_9682552_10003796/,https://{redacted by me}/vessels/akebono-maru_9554729_2866687/,https://{redacted by me}/vessels/amani_9661869_9276632/,https://{redacted by me}/vessels/aman-sendai_9134323_2017277/,https://{redacted by me}/vessels/al-aamriya_9338266_25273/}

r = requests.get('https://{redacted by me}/vessels/amadi_9682552_10003796/')
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.status_code)
elif r.status_code == 300:
    print(r.status_code) #post url seperately to a defined api -- future
elif r.status_code == 404:
    print(r.status_code) #post url seperately to a defined api -- future for removal
data = r.content
data = data.decode("utf-8")
#print(data)

next_port_locode = data.split('locode: "')[1].split('"')[0].strip()
next_port_iso2 = data.split('iso2: "')[1].split('"')[0].strip()
next_port_name = data.split('iso2: "')[1].split('name: "')[1].split('"')[0].strip()
next_port_eta = data.split('eta: moment("')[1].split('"')[0].strip()
next_port_latitude = float(data.split('latitude: ')[1].split(',')[0].strip())
next_port_longitude = float(data.split('longitude: ')[1].split('\n')[0].strip())


datajson = {
            "next_port_locode": next_port_locode,
            "next_port_iso2": next_port_iso2,
            "next_port_name": next_port_name,
            "next_port_eta": next_port_eta,
            "next_port_latitude": next_port_latitude,
            "next_port_longitude": next_port_longitude,
           }

print(datajson)

requests.post("https://{redacted by me}/api/Moments", json=datajson)
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to follow python tutorials, e.g. on what for loops are: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp `for url in myString: ...`

Comment: Your tip was all that I needed.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just need to work on your Python basics, this should do it.  Check out using `lists` and `for` loops.  Good luck!

```
import requests

myString = ['https://{redacted by me}/vessels/amadi_9682552_10003796/','https://{redacted by me}/vessels/akebono-maru_9554729_2866687/','https://{redacted by me}/vessels/amani_9661869_9276632/','https://{redacted by me}/vessels/aman-sendai_9134323_2017277/','https://{redacted by me}/vessels/al-aamriya_9338266_25273/'}

for myURL in myString:
    r = requests.get(myURL)
    if r.status_code == 200:
    .
    .
    .
```